# Android Fragments stored as array in FragmentPagerAdapter not refreshed after leaving and coming back to app

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I'm having a strange issue with fragment views not refreshing properly, but it only happens after the app is closed and re-opened after some amount of time.

I have a `TabSwitcherActivity` which contains a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` switches between 3 fragments, and each fragment represents a different view of the same information. There are certain events that can happen which will cause the information to become stale, so the fragments need to be notified to refresh the view. To accomplish this, my `TabSwitcherActivity` has a method called `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will iterate the 3 fragments and tell them to refresh. Here is (I think) the most relevant code:

```
public class TabSwitcherActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Used to keep track of the child fragments of this activity so we can update their list adapters.
        mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        // Set up the view pager and tab adapter.
        setContentView(R.layout.pager_layout);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentOne.class.getName()));
        mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTwo.class.getName()));
        mFragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentThree.class.getName()));
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ListPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments));
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        for (Fragment fragment : mFragments) {
        if (fragment instanceof IDataSetChangedListener) {
            ((IDataSetChangedListener) fragment).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works as intended the first time the app is launched. The problem is that after the app is closed and re-opened some time later, calling `TabSwitcherActivity.notifyDataSetChanged()` while the app is running does not update the fragment views (this works the first time the app is started after a reboot). This leads me to believe that there is a life cycle situation with the fragments that I'm not handling correctly. Any idea what this might be? It occurs to me that If the fragments are destroyed and recreated, they are probably not correctly stored in my `mFragments` array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in case others have a similar problem to what I had. I was able to resolve the problem based on the comments from invertigo. I'll post some generified pieces of the important parts of the code.

As I suspected, the fragments stored in the array were not correctly updated if they were destroyed and re-created by the application. (This would sometimes happen when the application was closed and re-opened.) It was a little bit tricky to remove the array since I was using it to store the fragments for my tabs in my `FragmentPagerAdapter` implementation.

Here is my old `ListPagerAdapter` class:

```
public class ListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragments;

    public ListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        mFragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        return ((ITitledFragment) mFragments.get(position)).getTitle();
    }
}
```

Here is my new implementation, which removes the problem caused by the array holding bad fragment references:

```
public class ListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {    
    private static final int FRAGMENT_ONE_POSITION = 0;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_TWO_POSITION = 1;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_THREE_POSITION = 2;
    private static final int COUNT = 3;

    public ListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);  
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case FRAGMENT_ONE_POSITION:
            return new FragmentOne();
        case FRAGMENT_TWO_POSITION:
            return new FragmentTwo();
        case FRAGMENT_THREE_POSITION:
            return new FragmentThree();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FragmentOne.getTitle();
        case 1:
            return FragmentTwo.getTitle();
        case 2:
            return FragmentThree.getTitle();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, the only remaining problem is how to have the my `TabSwitcherActivity` class update all of the fragments when they are stale. As invertigo pointed out, this can be done with tags. However, I decided to use an approach where each fragment registers itself with the activity when it is created, and unregisters itself before it is destroyed. The activity can iterate registered fragments to update them.

The Relevant code from `TabSwitcherActivity`:

```
class TabSwitcherActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private List<Fragment> mFragments;

    private void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Used to keep track of the child fragments of this activity so we can update their list adapters.
        mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        // Set up the view pager and tab adapter.
        setContentView(R.layout.pager_layout);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ListPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    public void startTrackingFragment(Fragment f) {
        mFragments.add(f);
    }

    public void stopTrackingFragment(Fragment f) {
        mFragments.remove(f);
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        for (Fragment fragment : mFragments) {
            if (fragment instanceof IDataSetChangedListener) {
                ((IDataSetChangedListener) fragment).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that, all that remains is to have the fragments register themselves for updates:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements IDataSetChangedListener {
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ((TabSwitcherActivity) getActivity()).startTrackingFragment(this);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        ((TabSwitcherActivity) getActivity()).stopTrackingFragment(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always just refresh the data in onResume() of your fragments, or call notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume() of your activity.

re: "It occurs to me that If the fragments are destroyed and recreated, they are probably not correctly stored in my mFragments array."
Instead of storing the fragments in an array, use the fragment manager to fetch the fragments by tag or id.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)

Comment: I should have been more clear - the views may need to be updated while the app is in use. Sometimes `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called while the app is active.

The fragment manager tip might be useful - I'll look into that.

Comment: my suggestion is to update the data in onResume() of your fragments *in addition to* whatever manual updates you want to perform via notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Ahh - sorry for the confusion, I must not have described the problem well in my first post. The problem is not that the views are stale when the app starts the second time. Rather, after the app is started the second time, calling `TabSwitcherActivity.notifyDataSetChanged()` while the app is running does not cause the fragment views to be updated. I'll edit my original post to be more clear.

Comment: ah, makes sense. then i'd check your array, i think you are right in that the fragments are not being persisted in the array, but you should be able to retrieve them via `getFragmentManger().findFragmentByTag()`